# Did they actually hold the 76th Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games

The ending of *Mockingjay* really bugs me —

> [Why did Katniss agree to another Hunger Games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/why-did-katniss-agree-with-president-coin), this time with the Capitol's children?

If we accept that it was subterfuge (as the [top answer to the related question states](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11343/348)), then the question still remains: did they actually go through with it? Or did Katniss' little trick with her bow

> namely, killing President Coin instead of Snow

derail things?

Comment: Katniss didn't want games she only voted yes so she could get rid of coin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's hardly an official source, but it doesn't make sense for them to carry it out afterwards.  The entire point of Katniss agreeing was (IMO)

> to set up Coin for assassination as revenge for Prim's death.

[From the wiki:](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/76th_Hunger_Games)

> However, minutes later, Katniss assassinates President Coin when she was supposed to be executing President Snow, **which prevents the proposal from being carried out**.

Comment: Thank God. I could not imagine a worse way to end the story. More children giving their lives and this time all for nothing. Katniss may have wanted the Games to happen but she stopped with Coin's death.

Comment: -1 for poor sourcing. Your conclusion is correct, but there's [better argumentation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11343/31394) for that than a quote from [the worst, most unreliable wikia I've ever seen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/196207/31394).

Answer (score 14):

The Epilogue of Mockingjay, narrated by Katniss, explained that the Hunger Games were done forever.

> The arenas have been completely destroyed, the memorials built, there are no more Hunger Games. But they teach about them at school, and the girl [Katniss and Peeta's daughter] knows we played a role in them.

Comment: I'm not sure this proves anything. It could be "there are no more Hunger games... AFTER that last one with Capitol children"

Comment: -1 because, as @DVK points out, this doesn't settle the actual question one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Paylor would have let the 76th Hunger Games happen. I mean you're all talking about what Katniss says to prove this but did you ever think about the new president and whether or not she would agree to it? Even if she had to she would've had to build another arena and all the game makers that knew what to do are probably dead. Also, Katniss probably wouldn't have had kids of there had been a Hunger Games with 'kids' in. It would have scared her too much watching them die (she would think it was her fault), no matter that they were Capitol children. To her no child should be killed. So she wouldn't have had children, because she would be scared or maybe anytime she looked at them, she would think 'maybe I'll kill you too' or 'I killed people like you. It's my fault they're dead.' I'm not saying it is her fault but that's what she would think. 
I know this doesn't prove anything but if you just read and think for a moment it shows that there was no reason to have a 76th Hunger Games.